# Finding $\frac{a+b}{a-b}$ such that $a^2+b^2=6ab$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For $a,b > 0$ such that $a^2+b^2=6ab$ .How to find $\frac{a+b}{a-b}$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have $a^2+b^2=6ab$.

To both sides, add $2ab$ to obtain, $(a+b)^2 = 8ab$.

Similarly, subtract $2ab$ to obtain, $(a-b)^2=4ab$.

Thus, $\left(\dfrac{a+b}{a-b}\right)^2 = 2$.

So ultimately $\frac{a+b}{a-b}= \pm\sqrt2$.

Answer (score 6):

$$(a-b)^2=4 a b = (a+b)^2-(a-b)^2$$

which means that

$$1 = \left ( \frac{a+b}{a-b}\right)^2 - 1$$

or

$$\frac{a+b}{a-b} =\pm \sqrt{2}$$

depending whether $a > b$ or not.

Comment: why don't you leave these questions to us kids? :P

Answer (score 3):

We have $$\frac{a^2+b^2}{2ab}=\frac31$$

Applying [componendo and dividendo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Componendo_and_dividendo),  $$\frac{a^2+b^2+2ab}{a^2+b^2-2ab}=\frac{3+1}{3-1}$$

$$\implies \left(\frac{a+b}{a-b}\right)^2=2$$

Comment: Could you please explain your first step? Did you just choose to divide both sides by $2ab$?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @gekkostate, yes, then applied   componendo and dividendo

Answer (score 2):

Note that you would have $ \ (a + b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2 = 8ab \ , $ and something similar for $ \ ( a - b )^2 \ $ ...